# Why is my event always null even though it is properly added at the calling function?

Tags: c#, events

(Info): I know this has been asked several times, but IMHO always the issue was that the Event wasn't really added at the calling funcation, which is not the case here.

I have the following class:

```
 public class FilePanel : BasePanel
{
    public event LinkClickedEventHandler FileOpen;
    private PlaylistElement _element;

    public FilePanel() : base()
    {
        AddControls(new PlaylistElement { Description = "lorem ipsom" });
    }

    public FilePanel(PlaylistElement element) : base(element)
    {
        AddControls(element);
    }

    private void AddControls(PlaylistElement element)
    {
        _element = element;
        ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
        var textControl = new Label { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Text = element.File.Title, Padding = new Padding(2, 2, 5, 2) };
        var linkControl = new LinkLabel { Dock = DockStyle.Right, TextAlign= System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleRight, Width = 200, Text = "Datei öffnen",  Padding = new Padding(2, 2, 5, 2) };
        tt.SetToolTip(linkControl, element.File?.FileReference);
        linkControl.Click += LinkControl_Click;
        this.Controls.Add(textControl);
        base.AddControls(element);
        this.Controls.Add(linkControl);

        this.Height = 50;
    }

    private void LinkControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileOpen?.Invoke(this, new LinkClickedEventArgs(_element.File.FileReference));
    }
}
```

This class is called the following way:

```
private void AddScheduleFile(RadCollapsiblePanel blockPanel, PlaylistElement element)
{
    var panel = new ScheduleControls.FilePanel(element);
    panel.FileOpen += Panel_FileOpen;
    blockPanel.Controls.Add(new ScheduleControls.FilePanel(element));
}
```

As you can see, the FileOpen-Event is assigned to the calling class.

But when I Break into `LinkControl_Click`, `FileOpen` is NULL nonetheless.

Comment: "As you can see, the FileOpen-Event is assigned to the calling class." - Well yes, for the panel that you create and then do nothing with...

Comment: You are right. But Mong Zhu was faster, Jon :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems that you fire the event in the wrong object. Although you register the event you do it for the `panel` object. But you add an entirely new object to the controls:

```
blockPanel.Controls.Add(new ScheduleControls.FilePanel(element));
```

if you now use this object to fire the event, you  will see that it is `null` because you have not registered it. Why not passing the original object to the controls?=! :

```
private void AddScheduleFile(RadCollapsiblePanel blockPanel, PlaylistElement element)
{
    var panel = new ScheduleControls.FilePanel(element);
    panel.FileOpen += Panel_FileOpen;
    blockPanel.Controls.Add(panel);
}
```